# How can I compare a DateTime object with doctrine 2.0 DateTime

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm working on a filter query that will return posts that are between certain dates, however, I'm unable figure out a way to compare the PHP DateTime object with the datetime in the database.  The filter component gives me the date in m/d/Y format, and the datetime in the database is in m/d/Y H:i:s format.

```
$posted_before = \DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $posted_before);
$posted_before->format("m/d/Y H:i:s");
$query .= " AND t.posted_date >= $posted_before";
```

I'm using Doctrine 2.0

Comment: I tried what you guys suggested.  I see that I was trying to inject the object.  However, the < and > comparison doesn't seem to work for pulling posts that are before or after a particular date.  I printed out that segment of the query and it looks like this:  AND t.posted_date <= '01/25/2012 09:57:57' AND t.posted_date >= '01/25/2012 09:57:57'   ---

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are injecting an object into your string, try storing the return value of `format();`. Also format the date according to [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) formatting:

```
$posted_before = \DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $posted_before);
$posted_date = $posted_before->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query .= " AND t.posted_date >= $posted_date";
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to format the Datetime object, you can use setParameter method:

```
$qb->where('t.posted_date >= :minDatetime');
$qb->setParameter('minDatetime', $minDatetime);
```